# Unable to deploy to a local server folder asp.net successfully

Tags: asp.net, publish

I am new to asp.net

Below is my project file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <Target Name="GatherAllFilesToPublish">
      </Target>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
        <ProductVersion>
        </ProductVersion>
        <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
        <ProjectGuid>{F5500ADD-969D-45A1-A175-0D60ECE982B2}</ProjectGuid>
        <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
        <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
        <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
        <RootNamespace>SampleWebService</RootNamespace>
        <AssemblyName>SampleWebService</AssemblyName>
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
        <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
        <TargetFrameworkProfile />
        <Use64BitIISExpress />
        <IISExpressSSLPort />
        <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
        <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
        <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
        <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
      </PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <Optimize>false</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
        <Optimize>true</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="System" />
        <Reference Include="System.Data" />
        <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
        <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
        <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel.Web" />
        <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
        <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
        <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
        <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
        <Reference Include="System.Web" />
        <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
        <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
        <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
        <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
        <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="WebService.asmx" />
        <Content Include="Web.config">
          <SubType>Designer</SubType>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="Web.Debug.config">
          <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
          <SubType>Designer</SubType>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="Web.Release.config">
          <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
        </Content>
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="WebService.asmx.cs">
          <DependentUpon>WebService.asmx</DependentUpon>
          <SubType>Component</SubType>
        </Compile>
        <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="App_Data\" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\CommonLib\CommonLib.csproj">
          <Project>{1B3AF307-D36B-498F-8618-B53688B4FFC6}</Project>
          <Name>CommonLib</Name>
        </ProjectReference>
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml" />
        <None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile1.pubxml" />
        <None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile2.pubxml" />
        <None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile3.pubxml" />
        <None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile4.pubxml" />
        <None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\Profile1.pubxml" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
      <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
      <ProjectExtensions>
        <VisualStudio>
          <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
            <WebProjectProperties>
              <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
              <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
              <DevelopmentServerPort>64867</DevelopmentServerPort>
              <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
              <IISUrl>
              </IISUrl>
              <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
              <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
              <CustomServerUrl>
              </CustomServerUrl>
              <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
            </WebProjectProperties>
          </FlavorProperties>
        </VisualStudio>
      </ProjectExtensions>
      <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
           Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
      <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
      </Target>
      <Target Name="AfterBuild">
      </Target>
      -->
    </Project>
```

When i tried to deploy to a local server by folder,the bin/Release/Publish
does not contain anything.
Also tried the Debug mode too,bin/Debug/Publish folder contains nothing.

When i run publish,below is the following output,

```
1>------ Publish started: Project: SampleWebService, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Connecting to D:\Project\Sample\SampleWebService\SampleWebService\bin\Release\publish\...
1>Publishing folder /...
1>Web App was published successfully file:///D:/Project/Sample/SampleService/SampleWebService/bin/Release/publish/
1>
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The publish log indicates success but no files inside my publish folder.
i am using visual studio 2017 but the project files should be built using 2010
Based on the following lines:
$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />

V10.0 means visual studio 2010 ,am i right?
Anyone has any idea what is wrong,do i have to use visual studio 2010 to publish my project instead of the latest 2017 version?

Comment: Can you try to publish into another folder not in the bin folder ?

Comment: the bin folder will create by itself,i choose the  D:\Project\Sample\SampleWebService\SampleWebService during the wizard

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

The cause is i put the following lines in the project file to resolve the gatherallfilestopublish issue:
  
  </Target>-->

Found another way to resolve the issue as outlined by below forum:
https://forums.asp.net/t/1838524.aspx?The+target+GatherAllFilesToPublish+does+not+exist

Re: The target GatherAllFilesToPublish does not exist

I fixed the issue by doing following modifications to the Project file. have VS 2012 and the web application was MVC 4

1. Unload the project and start editing the csproj file.
2. Added following lines.

10.0
    $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)

3. Added following lines.(Note that some of the Import statments may already exisits. In such case you do not need to add them.

Project file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!--<Target Name="GatherAllFilesToPublish">
  </Target>-->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{F5500ADD-969D-45A1-A175-0D60ECE982B2}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>SampleWebService</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>SampleWebService</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <Use64BitIISExpress />
    <IISExpressSSLPort />
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!--added-->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <!--added-->
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="WebService.asmx" />
    <Content Include="Web.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Web.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="WebService.asmx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>WebService.asmx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>Component</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="App_Data\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CommonLib\CommonLib.csproj">
      <Project>{1B3AF307-D36B-498F-8618-B53688B4FFC6}</Project>
      <Name>CommonLib</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml" />
    <None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile1.pubxml" />
    <None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile2.pubxml" />
    <None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile3.pubxml" />
    <None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile4.pubxml" />
    <None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile5.pubxml" />
    <None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\Profile1.pubxml" />
  </ItemGroup>
 <!-- <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />-->
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>64867</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>
          </IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```